# pyCharm cant access packages directory

Tags: python, directory, pycharm

I have created a new pyCharm file and im trying to bring in my anaconda 3.7 environment (that ive been using for Jupyter) that has all my packages. But for some reason the only packages that are brought in a few random ones. First image shows PyCharm interpreter the second the folder directory with all my packages.

How do i tell Pycharm

- use this version of python
- and use this specific directory's packages

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## add modules in pycharm from a specific directory

import sys

sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/Users/MyNAME/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages')

## import a whole package

import pandas as pd

## import sub-module

from arcgis.gis import GIS

Answer (score 0):

Switch to `conda` package manager:

[image]

Comment: yeh but with that I have fewer packages i can see for some reason?
Python version problem maybe?